# $p$-simple integers from between $n$ and $n+p-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\ p\ $ be an arbitrary prime. Then an integer $\ s\ $ is called $p$-simple $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ s\ $ is not divisible by any prime $\ q<p.\ $

Could you prove my conjecture (or is it known one way or another?):

> For every prime $\ p\ $ and for every every integer $\ n\ $ there exists a $p$-simple integer $\ s\ $ such that $\ n\le s < n+p$.

---

**NOTES:**

- There is a $p$-simple integer such that $\ n\le s<n+p\ $ for every $\ n\ $ such that $\ -2\cdot p < n \le p$.
- If the conjecture holds restricted to all positive integers $\ n\ $ then it holds in full, for all integers $\ n$.
- There is a $p$-simple integer $\ s\ $ such that $\ p+1 \le s\le 2\cdot p\ $ (**Chebyshev**--actually, $\ s\ $ can be a prime).
- The conjecture holds for $\ n=2\ $ (trivial); and for $\ n=3\ $ (at least one of the three consecutive integers is odd); and for $\ p=5\ $ (among any $5$ consecutive integers, at the most $3$ are even, at the most $2$ are divisible by $3$, whole one of the even ones is divisible by $3$ when there are there three even numbers--thus one of these consecutive $5$ integers is not divisible by $2$ nor by $3$).

Comment: Nope.  Large gaps between primes.  Gerhard "Should I Mention Jacobsthal's Function?" Paseman, 2016.06.15.

Comment: In particular, p=13 and n=114 is a small counterexample.  The previous comment shows that n+p-1 can be replaced by n +Cp for any constant C.  Gerhard "Has A Preprint About It" Paseman, 2016.06.15.

Comment: I suppose you meant, for every integer $n$ **and for every prime $p$** there exists etc., etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - yes, for every p and every p... I thought that I've written according to a convention which means this: F(x) means for every x: F(x). But I will make it clearer; indeed, it's always better to make things clearer. Thank you, Gerry.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman -- indeed, your p=13 and n=114 is a counterexample; you're welcome to post it to make the thread easier to read. (The example is economic since 114-1 as well as 114+13 are both primes).

Comment: +1 for the nice notation for "is defined as equivalent to" I had never seen before. Is it yours?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, I am not seeing the quoted phrase anymore anywhere but in your comment. If I used it then indeed I made it up.

Comment: BTW, my comment where I answered the very first comment by Geard (before there were other comments) has vanished virtually immediately, and it's not there (or at least I cannot see it).

Comment: I think @Sylvain is referring to that arrow-colon-arrow notation in the first line of the body of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - thank you! (I am dense). Yes, it's mine.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, thank you. Yes, I've introduced the symbol $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ (and several other) some years ago. Perhaps search engines can find them (however, the search engines are far from perfect).

Comment: Indeed, search engines are very far from perfect.

Comment: When I draft my (rarer and rarer) ideas on a sheet of paper, I usually use colon-leftrightarrow for the same purpose. But yours is much better, as it is symmetrical.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN -- there are trade-offs. (The symbol $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ appears all over MO in my notes around here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conjecture is false. Rankin (1938) proved that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all $x>20$, there exist at least $$ c x\frac{(\log x)(\log\log\log x)}{(\log\log x)^2} $$
consecutive integers, each of which are divisible by some prime less than $x$. Note that the fraction here tends to infinity as $x\to\infty$. More recently, [Ford-Green-Konyagin-Maynard-Tao (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029) improved the denominator $(\log\log x)^2$ above to $\log\log x$, and this is the state-of-the-art.

On the positive side, Sylvester (1892) proved that for any $n>p$, there is an integer $n\leq s<n+p$, which has at least one prime factor exceeding $p$. A simple proof was given by [Erdős (1934)](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf).

Comment: Sylvester died in 1897, so that was a posthumous publication in 1912?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You are right, 1912 is the year his collected works got published. The year of the result is 1892!

Answer (score 3):

Given a prime $p$, let $P$ be the product of the primes less than $p$. A $p$-simple integer $s$ is then an integer satisfying $\gcd(P,s)=1$ (so $s$ is a *totative* of $P$), and the posted conjecture asserts that any interval of $p$ consecutive integers contains at least one such $s$, and this means the difference between two consecutive totatives of $P$ is at most $p$.

This holds for $p\leq 11$ (as $g(210)=10$), but not for larger $p$, as the example in the comments with $p=13$ and $n=114$ shows.  The Jacobsthal function $g(m)$ which measures the maximal difference between consecutive totatives of $m$ is larger than $k=\Omega(m)$, the number of distinct prime factors of $m$, and when restricted to primorials $P$ is easily shown to grow at least as fast as $2q$, where $q$ is the largest but one prime less than $p$.  As mentioned in another answer, Rankin (and earlier, Westzynthius in 1931) showed that for any positive $C$, there are some $m$ with $g(m) \gt Ck\log k$.

Gerhard "Now I've Mentioned Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2016.06.16.

Comment: Gerard, what are *totatives*?

Comment: Totatives of a positive integer n are numbers coprime to n.  Often totatives  of n are restricted to  being less than n and greater than 0, but I don't place that restriction.  Gerhard "Now I've Also Mentioned Totatives" Paseman, 2016.06.16.